# При нажатии на LinearLayout, нажимается со 2го раза

Tags: android

Есть три LinearLayout-а, при нажатии на которых должен меняться их фон (как при нажатии на кнопку). При нажатии на первый `LinearLayout` все хорошо, и `onClick()` срабатывает, но если нажать на 2й или 3й, то ничего не произойдет, только если нажать 2 раза подряд на один `LinearLayout`, то на второй клик сработает `onClick()`. Как правильно реализовать данную функцию?

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/pressed_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/pressed_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/pressed_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**pressed_layout.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime">

        <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"
            android:state_focused="true" 
            android:state_pressed="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:state_focused="false" 
            android:state_pressed="false" />

    </selector>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        LinearLayout layout3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        layout1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"clicked layout1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        layout2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"clicked layout2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        layout3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"clicked layout3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Comment: так вообще теперь ничего не работает

Comment: Попробуйте в селектор добавить ещё цвет для деволтного сотояния + покажите как вы слушатели нажатий повесили.

Comment: добавил цвет для дефолтного сотояния,все так же

Comment: Попробуйте вот это всем линеарам добавить `android:clickable="true"` т.е. без `android:focusable="true"        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Comment: так работает нормально но без фона клика

Comment: Т.е. тоасты показываются, но фон не подсвечивается?

Comment: Возможно у вас селектор не очен правильный в смысле проставления состояний. Попроббуйте системный поставить, т.е. `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: все так же,я так понял 1й клик ставит фокус на лайаут а второй уже выводит в onClick,а можно тогда как то навести фокус на все елемны?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что у вас в родительском `LinearLayout` не выставлен атрибут `android:descendantFocusability` - [тынц](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability)

Этот атрибут управляет куда попадают ваши клики или к родителю, или к потомку или к обоим и в каком порядке.

Поиграйтесь с этим атрибутом. Ну и не забывайте про советы коллег в комментариях, они тоже важны, хотя и вторичны.

Comment: Вы правы, с атрибутом `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` в родительском `LinearLayout` все стало работать как должно,большое спасибо!